# I want to make a program that take integer input from user and sum those. There is no fixed amount of parameter

Tags: python, input

I want to make a program that take integer input from user and sum those. There is no fixed amount of parameter. So I write this code. But there is an error. Hope I will get a solution.

***Code:***

```
def sum(*args):
    tmp = 0
    for number in args:
        tmp = tmp + number
    return tmp

temp = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
sum(temp)
print(temp)
```

***Error:***

```
10 20 30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharm/test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    sum(temp)
  File "D:/PyCharm/test2.py", line 4, in sum
    tmp = tmp + number
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Note that `sum` is already defined to do just this.  And you aren't doing anything with what `sum` returns.

Comment: @all agreed, there should be a problem solved within the definition of sum - but why (re)define sum, when the built-in sum doesn't even have this problem? It already accepts lists as argument...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors:

after calling `sum(temp)`, you should assign result to a variable and print it.

`sum` should take list, not *list.

Your code should look like this:

```
def sum(args):
    tmp = 0
    for number in args:
        tmp = tmp + number
    return tmp

temp = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
result = sum(temp)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
$ python3 suminputs.py
3 4 5
12 
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap your list before passing it in:

```
sum(*temp)
```

That way, `args` will be the list `[10, 20, 30]`. Instead if you just call `sum(temp)` then args will be a list of the arguments so it will just end up being a single element list of a list `[[10, 20, 30]]` which is not what you want

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum()` function puts all arguments passed to it in a tuple, because you used `*args`. You called the `sum()` function with one argument, which is a list. So `args` is a tuple with one element, a list:

```
>>> def demo(*args): return args
...
>>> demo([42, 81])
([42, 81],)
```

You then loop over the tuple, and tried to sum the list object.

Either *remove* the `*` from the `args` parameter (and just accept a single argument), or pass the *values* of your list to `sum()` by using the `*` in the call too:

```
def sum(args):
    # ... all the same code

# ...
result = sum(temp)
```

or

```
result = sum(*temp)
```

You are also *ignoring the return value* of the `sum()` function and are printing the inputs. If you wanted to print the result, then pass that result to `print()`. In the above examples I added a `result` variable, print that variable.